# WebForms Repeater, setting text-box attribute to be used as identifier on Save

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am building a relatively simple WebForm that has two columns with about 15 fixed input fields in each and 1 that is "Other" which has count of (n).

I have created a Repeater like so:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptClientItems" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptClientItems_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <asp:Label ID="lblItemType" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtOtherItemTypeDescription" runat="server" Visible="false"  CssClass="lblandinput"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtItemTextBoxArea" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now in my `ItemDataBound()` function I loop over all my DataBase elements and populate values in these text areas and label.

**Issue 1** is, when I click `SAVE()`. In my save function I have no idea which `Textbox` belongs to which item in the DataBase.

**Issue 2** my `txtOtherItemTypeDescription` is dynamically created so on save I am using `Request.Form.GetValues("key")` to get all the values however I feel this is not the most productive way to do this as this also leads to above issue after first save editing these items will be a pain.

I am relatively new to this so good example and explanation will go a long way. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep using a Repeater, the simplest solution would be to add a Label that is hidden since a Repeater does not have an `DataKeyField` property. Yo can use that label to store the ID.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="hiddenID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Is your Save method you can then loop the Repeater Items and get the value of the TextBox and the Label.

```
foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptClientItems.Items)
{
   Label lb = item.FindControl("hiddenID") as Label;
   TextBox tb = item.FindControl("txtItemTextBoxArea") as TextBox;

   Label1.Text += lb.Text + ": " + tb.Text + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I will give this a go!! Would looping over repeater items work with the OTHER input that can have (n) count eg> ID = 5 has (10 items in repeater)

Comment: Yes, you can use FindControl like this `FindControl("txtItemTextBoxArea" + i)`